# Given Date parameter is considered as Date Time parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I'm writing a stored procedure in sql!

I have to get records in the particular date.

I am using this query:

```
Declare @FromDate datetime
set @FromDate = '06/02/2014'

select * from Table where Date = @FromDate
```

Actually, in the Database there are 10 records in that date, but it is showing only two records because the `@FromDate` is taking like this `06/02/2014 00:00:00.000`

If I write the query like this it means it works correctly!

```
select * from Table
where Date between '2014-08-28 00:00:00.000' and '2014-08-28 23:59:59.999'
```

How to solve this? I need to get all the records in that particular date.

Please help me !

Comment: If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer and you need only the date (no time-portion), you should use the `DATE` datatype which does exactly that - store **only** the date, without time portion, and thus selecting a single date becomes very easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert `DateTime` to `Nvarchar` your issue would be solved.

**Try this query:**

```
Declare @Date datetime='2014-08-28 00:00:00.000'

select * from Table
where  CONVERT(nvarchar(20),Date,105) = CONVERT(nvarchar(20),@Date,105)
```

Comment: @Jake745 Not a good idea if you want to use an index on the date column to find the rows you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If `@FromDate` is of data type `datetime` and `Table.Date` is also of data type `datetime` then:

```
Declare @FromDate datetime = '2014-06-02';

Select Table.Date
From Table
Where Table.Date >= @FromDate And Date < DateAdd(day, 1, Table.Date)
```

Above, we create an inclusive lower boundary (anything equal to or later than 2014-06-02) and an exclusive upper boundary (anything earlier than 2014-06-03), but with a variable defined just once. So, effectively the query checks `2014-06-02 <= FromDate < 2014-06-03`.